# WAMP server stays yellow, though server is functioning normally?

Tags: apache, testing, wamp, wampserver

I turned on my computer today and it performed three unexpected updates (I had updates disabled, yet for some reason it continues to update). Now, my wampserver will launch and will run essentially normally but the icon refuses to change to green. I don't know why it's doing this and am worried that it may have a negative impact in someway.

Couldn't find much about it elsewhere. Sorry for the lack of details, I really don't know what the issue could even be.

**Edit:**

I cleared my apache error log and restarted the server. Starting the server gave me this:

```
[Wed Mar 12 16:48:50.672813 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4540:tid 564] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Mar 12 16:48:50.672813 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4540:tid 564] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Wed Mar 12 16:48:50.672813 2014] [core:notice] [pid 4540:tid 564] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Wed Mar 12 16:48:50.674815 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4540:tid 564] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 716
[Wed Mar 12 16:48:51.206356 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 716:tid 508] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Can someone explain to me what this means? It seems normal to be honest, so i'm unsure what it all means.

**Edit:**

Here is my mysql log, this looks problematic..

```
    2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: .\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Binlog end
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: This log looks fine then. So its MYSQL thats not starting, can you repeat for MySQL

Comment: As requested, I've updated the main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not actually created any INNODB databases you could try this.

Delete these 3 files,

```
ib_logfile0
ib_logfile1
ibdata1
```

Restart the MySQL service by

```
left click wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Restart service
```

With luck MySQL will recreate those files when it see's they are missing like it does the first time you start MySQL after an install.

Comment: This did solve it. However I had important data, so I copied the files  to my desktop and had it fix itself. Then after it was done, I tried putting it back and now my wampserver seems to be running fine again

Comment: Thats ok then, I hope it wont bit you in the behind later!

Answer (score 0):

This is the error.

```
2014-03-12 16:52:57 8772 [ERROR] InnoDB: .\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
```

Provided you didnt move anyof the mysql data folders then do the following

Left click the wamp icon> Mysql > my.ini

at the end of the file write

innodb_force_recovery = 2

Save and restart all services. If it starts up , stop the service, remove the line and restart.

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything sadly.

Comment: make sure the file ibdata1 exists at  c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlX.X.X\data

Comment: is your harddrive nearly full?

Comment: It's a small hard drive, but it still has almost 60 gigs open.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this exact same issue: "[ERROR] InnoDB: .\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode". Turned out these files:

```
ib_logfile0
ib_logfile1
ibdata1
```

were being locked by a stubborn mysqld.exe process (wouldn't terminate when attempting to stop all WAMP services or on exiting WAMP).

Used [Unlocker](http://filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) to identify locking process and kill. Restarted WAMP, working sucessfully.