# WAMP won't recognise its own Apache service (even though Apache is working)

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I've been happily using WAMP for years without problems. Now, the icon is orange. When I click on the Apache service menu, then "start/resume", "restart" and "stop" are greyed out, as if the service isn't installed.

But here's the thing: the wampapache64 service *is* installed, and actually works. I can install it and remove it using WAMP, I just can't start or restart it from there, nor see a green icon.

I'm aware of dozens of "my WAMP icon is orange" posts here. These come closest to describing my problem ([I'm getting a Service Unavailable on wamp, but everything is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125047/im-getting-a-service-unavailable-on-wamp-but-everything-is-running), [WAMP server stays yellow, though server is functioning normally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363170/wamp-server-stays-yellow-though-server-is-functioning-normally)) but even those don't address this specific issue.

(The problem started when I clicked on the Apache version number in the WAMP menu, which I believe refreshes some config files.)

I'm using WAMP 2.5 64-bit, Windows 10. Apache is 2.4.9

Comment: Are you running WAMPServer (wampmanager.exe) "as Administrator" or have you tried to run it from a normal account?

Comment: @RiggsFolly WAMPServer asks for administrative privileges every time it starts (i.e. I get a UAC popup). My Windows user account is an admin account.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with the same issue with Wamp on Win 10 caused by one of the processes coliding with apache on port 80. All resolved by following steps:

- open command line under as an administrator
- make sure it is process with PID 4 listening to port 80:

netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:80

- change http process to use another port (i.e. 8000):

netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0:8000

- restart http service

net stop http

net start http

- restart Xamp processes

Comment: When I enter `netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:80`, I'm told that process 3148 is listening, which is wampapache64.

Comment: Try to kill the process i.e. via cmd line "Taskkill /PID 3148 /F" and start it directly from Wamp